# How to make Xcode recognise Objective-C commands in order to connect to Firebase?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Newbie here. In short: I'm using Arduino to count how many cars enter my garage and have the data sent to firebase. I was able to connect/read/write using Swift 4. Therefore, I decided to install a pod [this one](https://cocoapods.org/pods/LMGaugeView) to improve the design of the app. The pod is written in objective-C (I've never used the language), so I thought it would be easier to have the firebase in the same class and language as the pod.

Since I have some code written in Swift 4, I decided to create a bridging header in order to "mix and match" both languages in the same project.

Therefore, the issues I am currently facing are:

1 - In the `LMViewController.m` file I've added:

```
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseDatabase;
```

along with this code inside `- (void)viewDidLoad` method:

```
[FIRApp configure];

@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref;

self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
```

This code automatically raises red flags due to the fact that it is not recognising it. I am using the code exactly as specified on google's firebase website. [Firebase for ios](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).

2 - I have also tried to add the `import FirebaseDatabase` within swift appDelegate. No success in the `.m` file tho.

I would appreciate your help in order to understand how can I make xcode not give me errors when creating a firebase reference in order to read from it and assign the value to the pod code.

Comment: You can't have a `@property` declaration in the middle of your `viewDidLoad` implementation.

Comment: @Gereon thank you for answering. In this case, should I create a new method to add the `@property`? or just add it outside the `LMViewController.m`?